# How to use Polymorphism in java using abstract class?

Tags: java, class, inheritance, polymorphism, abstract

I have an abstract class named `Parent` that contains 2 abstract methods, and I want to override them in other classes that extend `Parent` class.

Here is my code :

```
abstract class Parent<T>
{
    public T a[];
    public abstract void sort(T a[]);
    public abstract void searc(T a[]);
}

class B_Sort<T> extends Parent<T>
{

    @Override
    public  void sort(T[] a) {
        for(int i =1; i< a.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < (a.length - i); j ++){
                if((((Comparable) (a[j])).compareTo(a[j+1])) > 0){
                    T tmp = a[j];
                    a[j] = a[j + 1];
                    a[j + 1] = tmp;
                }                
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void searc(T[] a) {
    }

}
```

This is my main class and main method to run the program :

```
public class ProjectX 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] a={2,3,1,5};
        Parent<Integer> cc=new B_Sort<>();
        cc.sort(a);        
    }    
}
```

However, `cc.sort(a)` didn't work correctly and I got an error on that line. My program didnt work!! why this is incorrect?

Comment: If you got an error, please post it, it will be easier to help you :)

Comment: @Nizil no i got a red title in my Netbeans IDE on that line , and my program didn't run

Comment: Your searc() method is empty! what is it supposed to do, that it isn't doing? Also like Nizil said, post the error please

Comment: You should change the parameter `T` to `T extends Comparable`. Then you won't have to cast, and you are safe from runtime `ClassCastException`s.

Answer (score 2):

Try to change

```
int [] a={2,3,1,5};
```

to

```
Integer [] a={2,3,1,5};
```

An array of primitives (such as `int[]`) can't be automatically converted to an array containing the boxed version of these primitives (`Integer[]`).

Comment: How can i do it for Double?

Comment: @Ahmadreza `Double [] a = {2.0,3.5,1.2}; Parent<Double> cc=new B_Sort<>();cc.sort(a);`